# Class magic - sorting objects by type automatically

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a kind of in-memory database into which I can put objects of any type that extends `EntityProxy`.  I want to index every object according to its type and id number (which every `EntityProxy` has - something simple like creating a HashMap for each type.

I could implement this manually with something like

```
public void put(Object o)
{
    if (o instanceof Car)
        carIndex.put(o.getId(), o);
    else if (o instanceof Bus)
        busIndex.put(o.getId(), o);

    ...
}
```

But of course I don't want to.  I want something more like

```
public void <T extends EntityProxy> put(T o)
{
   indexMap.get(o.class).put(o.getId(), o);
}
```

I just don't quit have the generics vocabulary to do this.  I don't know what the question mark means in template definitions, really - will something like

```
HashMap<Class<?>, HashMap<Long, EntityProxy>> indexMap
```

work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That map is OK; if you really need to add a tiny bit of constraint, just try:

```
Map<Class<? extends EntityProxy>, HashMap<Long, EntityProxy>> indexMap;
```

This would make sure the key class can only be an EntityProxy.class or subclass.

You can think of the question mark as some "anything", but anonymous. So `<?>` means *really anything* -- any `Object`, `<? extends EntityProxy>` means anything that fulfils this condition (passes the "`instanceof EntityProxy`" test).

The type safety here is less than desired, as you can still put anything as key and anything in that map. I mean, you can legally put this in the map:

```
indexMap.put(EntityProxy1.class, new HashMap<Long, EntityProxy2>());
```

(assuming `EntityProxy1` and `EntityProxy2` are both subclasses of `EntityProxy`) since there's no correlation between the key and the value. To enforce that, the `put()` method of the map would need to be declared like this:

```
<T extends EntityProxy> put(Class<T> key, HashMap<Long, T> value);
```

`T` is pretty much like `?` but the main difference is that it provides you with a name that you can refer to it in that context.
So, if I said that `?` stands for "anything", I would say `T` stands for "something", as you can refer to that something once you declare it.

But you would need a custom data structure for this, as `java.util.Map` does not provide this kind of constraint. If you're using it as shown in your code sample, I don't think you really need these enforcements.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation!  I've got this working quite elegantly, and since I can localize direct access to the Map in my Database code I think I won't worry about the lack of constraint.

Comment: instead of *passes the `instanceof EntityProxy` test* it should be *is a subtype of `EntityProxy`*, as this is a constraint on types, not on objects here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in this example I used List. You could easily replace this with your `Collection` class of choice and adapt accordingly.

```
public interface Classifiable {
    String classification();
}

public abstract class Automobile implements Classifiable {
    // String classification defined in child classes
}

public class Car extends Automobile {
    public String classification() { return "Car"; }
}

public class Bus extends Automobile {
    public String classification() { return "Bus"; }
}

public class AutoMap {
    Map<String,List<Automobile>> theMap = new Map<String,List<Automobile>>();

    public AutoMap() { }

    public void add(Automobile a) {
        String type = a.classification();
        List<Automobile> list = theMap.get(type);
        if(list == null) {
            list = new LinkedList<Automobile>();
            theMap.put(type,list);
        }
        list.add(a);
    }

    public List<Automobile> getAutosOfType(String type){
        return theMap.get(type);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Automobile> autos = getRandomAutos(); // defined somewhere? :)
    AutoMap theAutomap = new AutoMap();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the class name, it's as simple as:

```
public void <T extends EntityProxy> put(T o)
{
    HashMap map = indexMap.get(o.getClass().getName());
    if (map == null) 
    {
        map = new HashMap();
        indexMap.put(o.getClass().getName(), map);
    }
    map.put(o.getId(), o);
}
```

This code will create the required sub-hashmaps as you go along.

If you use `getClass().getName()` you get names on the form `com.mypackage.Bus`. If you're willing to handle name collisions and only want the simple name (in this case "Bus"), use `getClass().getSimpleName()` instead.

Comment: This could cause problems if you extend Car but want the extensions to still be treated like Car.

Comment: Yes, but from his example with o.class, that didn't seem to be what he was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Map<Class<?>, Map<Long, EntityProxy>> indexMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, Map<Long, EntityProxy>>();
```

and

```
public void put(EntityProxy entityProxy){ // generics don't add anything here
  ...
```

(I didn't test it)

Comment: Ah, you're right, a simple `EntityProxy` reference is more concise.